# Svn get current user

Tags: svn

How to get current user that is using svn on particular workstation?

can I use svn.exe executable with some switch to get that info.

Thanks.

Comment: With up-to-date SVN client you can run [`svn auth`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44678232/761095).

Answer (score 28):

In Linux,  you will find the following file in your home directory:

> ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple

In this file, you can see the "currently logged in user".

Comment: Yes. There is strangely named file there: 851320a14c12593c4c03577412869669. When file is opened with text editor, one of entries is: 'username
V 12
MartinBerger' where can be seen who is logged in. In this case, me.

Comment: One can use the following awk script to extract the user name from there:

`/^K / { key=1; val=0; }
/^V / { key=0; val=1; }
! /^[KV] / {
    if(key) { kname=$1; }
    if(val && kname == "username") {
        print $1;
        val = 0;
    }
}`

Put that into svnuser.awk and run like this:

`cat ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* | awk -f svnuser.awk`

Answer (score 14):

```
grep username ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* --after-context=2 | tail -1
```

**Explanation:**

1. Grep the file in `grep username ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/*` will look for username
2. `--after-context=2` will print +2 line after it encounters username

Output:

```
username
V 6
Bhavik
```

3. To print only the username
   use `| tail -1` will give me my username i.e `Bhavik`.

Hope this explains the code.

Comment: Sure

From the file in ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* it will look for username
--after-context=2 will print +2 line after it encounters username
username
V 6
Bhavik
lastly to get the username we | tail -1
will give me my username i.e Bhavik

Hope this explains my code

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that if you use multiple repositories you'll only list the user name of the last one.

Comment: so this one would get all of them: `for file in  ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* ; do grep username $file --after-context=2 | tail -1; done`

Comment: You don't need this. Just run `svn auth` with up to date SVN client version.

Comment: This works as well: `svn auth |grep -i username|awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 13):

There are several ways to find out stored logon credentials:

- Run `svn auth` to view credentials and certificates cached in SVN credential store (`%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth`).
- Run `cmdkey` to view the credentials stored in Windows Credential Manager.
- If your SVN server is integrated with Active Directory and supports Integrated Windows Authentication, your Windows logon credentials are used for authentication, but they are not cached. You can run `whoami` to find out your user account name .

BTW, don't miss [Michael Hackner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022958/761095):

> There's no such thing as the "current user that is using svn." Every
>   time an SVN command is submitted, credentials are supplied either
>   explicitly at the command prompt or implicitly through saved
>   credentials, which could include multiple users.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as the "current user that is using svn."  Every time an SVN command is submitted, credentials are supplied either explicitly at the command prompt or implicitly through saved credentials, which could include multiple users.

Comment: If you run `svn update`, it is obviously running as *some* user. The question is how to know what user that is.

Answer (score 7):

In Windows it is located in

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\
```

To find this directory, just go to `run` (<kbd>win-key</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>), paste the above command and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> or click on `Run` button.

For me, there was a file in folder `svn.simple`. It is a text file and it has info with saved authentication data. I have something like this:

```
...
K 8
username
V 6
kosta
END
```

Comment: You don't need this. Just run `svn auth` with up to date SVN client version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SVN+SSH, then, the username of the user for a given workstation is in the config file for SVN. Assuming Windows workstation, this file will be in C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Subversion folder. You can then write a script to get this name, and do what ever you need it for.

I think this is only for SVN+SSH setup. It cant work in other connectivity setups for SVN.

Comment: Thanks, the only file I have found is this one:

1d711cc713195841ccd6ab5d28737ce9 in

C:\Documents and Settings\irfan\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\
... 

It is different for every installation but it can be done...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the saved credentials: either you infer it from the log or you commit something (from the mentioned workstation/server) so you can see what the log says.

Answer (score 0):

The already suggested `svn auth` worked for me, but to have the *"ultimate"* confirmation, you can use a file that you modified and run

`svn info MODIFIED/FILE`

or

`svn log MODIFIED/FILE`

and see *Last Changed Author: XXXX*, or the history of the changes that lists also the user names.

Answer (score -1):

*Edit: Note this answer only applies to SVN versions before 1.9. If you using SVN version >1.9, then try the `svn auth` approach described in @bahrep's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44678232/529256)*

This is a bash script that I use, which I put in my ~/bin/ folder and called svn_whoami.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

debug=false

for ((i=1;i<=$#;i++)) do
    case ${!i} in

        -h|--help)
            programName=$( basename ${0} )
            echo "Usage:"
            echo "    ${programName} [-h|--help] [-d|--debug]"
            echo
            echo "Example:"
            echo "    ${programName} --debug"
            exit 0;
            ;;
        -d|--debug)
            debug=true;
            ;;

    esac;
done;

if [ "${debug}" == "true" ]; then
    echo "cat ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* | grep -A6 username --color";
fi;

cat ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* | grep -A6 svn:realmstring
```

Output:

```
$ svn_whoami.sh -d
cat ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* | grep -A6 username --color
svn:realmstring
V 53
<http://your.1st.url.name.here:80> Authorization Realm
K 8
username
V 5
yourUserName
--
svn:realmstring
V 45
<http://your.2nd.url.name.here:80> Authorization Realm
K 8
username
V 5
yourUserName
```

Comment: You don't need this. Just run svn auth with up to date SVN client version.

Comment: True, though this was only added as of SVN version 1.9 (see: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-auth). My company uses an earlier version on our build servers so I wasn't aware of it. I'll update my answer to make note that it only applies to pre 1.9 versions and to refer to your answer if using version 1.9.